# Via rotate orientation change layout without reload OnCreate()

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, orientation

I have 3 Layouts in different folders :

1.**layout/HomeLayout.axml** (where *layout* is an folder for layouts and HomeLayout.axml is an global axml file).
2.**layout-large-port/HomeLayout.amxl** (where *layout-large-port* is an folder for large(dimension of display) portrait and HomeLayout.axml is axml file).
3.**layout-large-land/HomeLayout.axml**(where is *layout-large-land* is an folder for large(dimension of display) landscape and HomeLayout.axml is axml file).

On this activity,i got ListView with some data and when i rotate my phone from ***portrait*** to ***landscape*** , i need to save all what i maked on **Portrait** mode(eachrow on listview have different things like *buttons*/*textview* and etc) and show on **Landscape**.

So what is done at current moment. On HomeActivity i declared this :

```
ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation
```

This snippet works well,but with big problem : after rotation(from **Portrait** to **Landscape**) remains layout Portrait. How can i fix that?

Also i tried to *override* method `OnConfigurationChanged` :

```
 public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);

            if(newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
                {
                   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProductsLayout); //system understand that now is Landscape and put correct layout;  
                }
            else
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProductsLayout); //same here
                }
```

So this method doesnt help me,because when i'm rotating phone,layout sets correct but with no data(listview is empty) and after that,when i'm trying to go back from **Landscape** to **Portrait**,layout sets correct but with empty list.
Any suggestions?

PS Sorry for my eng!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was(For me) to make acceptable design for portrait,which is it does not differ landscape mode(just use mechanisms like ***sum_weight*** and etc).

Answer (score 0):

Android will completely destroy and recreate your activity when a configuration changes; all views in that activity and the data they hold will also be discarded.

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

> **Caution:** Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the
>   user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the
>   system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the
>   screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load
>   alternative resources (such as the layout).

The standard mechanism for persisting data between configuration changes is to save the view data using the [`OnSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) callback of your `Activity` and then restore the data using the bundle provided through the `OnCreate` callback.

This is a rough example of how to do so:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public const string ARG_LIST_STATE = "list_state";
    ListView _listView;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        if (bundle != null) {
            // Existing data to restore!
            if (bundle.ContainsKey (ARG_LIST_STATE)) {
                var listState = bundle.GetStringArray (ARG_LIST_STATE);
                // TODO: Restore state into list view.
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        string[] listState= new string[5]; // TODO: Grab data from the list view and serialize it into the outState
        outState.PutStringArray(ARG_LIST_STATE, listState);

        base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
    }
}
```

Another example is provided by Xamarin [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/saving_state_walkthrough/).

I strongly recommend that you review the [activity lifecycle docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) so you can better understand how activities are managed by Android.

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes i'm know about this mecanism "onSaveInstance",but i need alternative(how i wrote on my question,to not reload OnCreate and show all data on landscape layout ). So is that possible?